# batch css sprites generator for css and images

Tags: css, cmd, generator, batch-processing

I searched hard for sprites generator that uses cmd-batch "i heard about "
the generator gets the css code like this:

```
.some-icon-1{
          background-image: url('some-ulr');
}
.some-icon-2{
          background-image: url('some-ulr');
}
```

and it gives only one "png" image, and the css displays the code as same as it was used:

[**CSS_Code** + **Images_ulrs**]  ==[**generate**]==>  [**CSS_Code** + **Only_one_image**]

please i do appreciate help to find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find [this](http://spritegen.website-performance.org/) sprite generator to be the best.

I hope this helps